# grouping shapes chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm trying to make a character with arms with chipmunk+cocos2d using Constraints. I read chipmunk needs to group the shapes for no collition between the parts.

I did

```
cpGroup *group;
cpShapeSetGroup(myShape1, group);
cpShapeSetGroup(myShape2, group);

cpSpaceAddConstraint(space_, cpPivotJointNew(bodyPin, body, cpv(pinX, pinY)));
cpSpaceAddConstraint(space_, cpRotaryLimitJointNew(body, armBody, 45, 90));
```

but both shapes keep colliding

thanks a lot

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: is the right way to add shapes to groups?

Answer (score 0):

That should have compiled with a warning. cpGroup is by default defined to be a unintptr_t type. So you should either give the group a unique integer identifier or cast a unique pointer (such as the game object that owns the shapes) to a uintptr_t.

What your code snippet above does is use the value of an uninitialized variable as the group. It should have worked though. Are you sure that shape1 and shape2 are the correct shapes?

Comment: pretty sure they are the correct shapes. An integer for cpGroup is fine. It works, but still having strange behaviours with constraints